# HTTP POST parameters not included when using IE Mode sitelist in Edge Chromium

Tags: http, internet-explorer, post, microsoft-edge

I have a legacy web application. The app needs to be opened in IE while the user opens it from Edge Chromium. I've added the URL to the EM site list XML on a NAS share. This works great for other legacy applications we have.

However, this application uses a HTTP POST request.

When a user navigates in Edge to the web application, it loads fine in a new IE11 screen.
But when you use the search, it opens in a new Window and it seems the parameters from the HTTP POST request are not included. This results in a null request.

Is there any setup needed to include the HTTP post request in IE mode? I can't find this anywhere in the MS documentation.

Comment: Does the website work well in real IE browser? How do you configure the IE mode? The issue might be related with neutral sites configuration for IE mode. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-sitelist#configure-neutral-sites) about how to configure neutral sites.

Comment: We've replaced the post request with a get request and solved the issue this way

Answer (score 0):

We've replaced the post request with a get request and solved the issue this way

Answer (score 0):

We had the same symptoms.  I did not verify that the http method was changed from POST to GET, but the form variables from a POST operation were not being transmitted to the next page.
We were able to get this working by adding the source page (the one with the form variables in it) to the Enterprise Mode Site List in Edge.
In Edge, paste the following into the address bar (without the quotes): "edge://compat/SiteListManager"

I checked the box to Allow Redirects and also used IE5 Document mode as the Compat Mode because that is what was indicated by f12 tools when running the same page in real IE 11.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-site-list-manager
And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-faq